# How do I initialize a django form with the previous input in a class based view?

Tags: python, django, forms, search, get

It displays a form on the top and when you submit it, it will only show some of the `Offer` instances that fits the filters. It works fine, but every time I submit it, the form returns to the initial value. How can I stop that? My form uses `GET` and the view is class-based. Also, the `__init__` in the form doesn't seem to be working.

views.py

```
class Search(ListView, FormMixin):
    model = Offer
    template_name = 'search.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    form_class = SearchForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.form = SearchForm(self.request.GET)
        if self.form.is_valid():
            data = self.form.cleaned_data
            qs = Offer.objects.all()
            if data['book'] != '0':
                qs = qs.filter(book_id=data['book'])
            qs = qs.filter(worn_degree__in=data['min_worn_degree'])
            qs = qs.filter(note_degree__in=data['min_note_degree'])
            return qs
        else:
            return Offer.objects.all()
```

search.html

```
{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="검색">
    </form>
    {% if object_list %}
        {% for object in object_list %}
            <p>{{ object.book.title }}</p>
            <p>{{ object.seller }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no offers.</vp>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.book = '0'
        self.min_worn_degree = 'abc'
        self.min_note_degree = 'abc'

    BOOK_CHOICE = tuple([('0', '모두')] + [(book.id, book.title) for book in Book.objects.all()])
    book = forms.ChoiceField(label='책', choices=BOOK_CHOICE)
    MIN_QUALITY = (
        ('a', '상 이상'),
        ('ab', '중 이상'),
        ('abc', '하 이상'),
    )
    min_worn_degree = forms.ChoiceField(label='낡은 정도', choices=MIN_QUALITY)
    min_note_degree = forms.ChoiceField(label='필기 정도', choices=MIN_QUALITY)
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in the `Search` class:

```
def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    form = SearchForm(self.request.GET)
    context = super(Search, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = form
    return context
```